# Get every references to some object in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All references to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988148/all-references-to-an-object)

I'm looking for a way to get a list of class/instance members who have a reference to some variable, in Java.

For instance, for this case:

```
public class MyClass {
    public LinkedList list; 
} 

public class MyOtherClass {
    public LinkedList list;
}

public class Program {

   public static void main(...) {
      LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
      MyClass c1 = new MyClass();
      MyOtherClass c2 = new MyOtherClass();

      c1.list = list;
      c2.list = list;
   }
}
```

At the end of the program we have 3 references for the `LinkedList` created on my first line of code in `Program.main`:

1. `Program.main.list`
2. `MyClass.list`
3. `MyOtherClass.list`

While the first one is a local variable (doesn't care for me), the others are instance fields. In this case, what I need it's some way to get, for 2. and 3., the reference to the objects (`MyClass` and `MyOtherClass`) and the field name that have the reference for the `LinkedList` created on line 1.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have to have the references at runtime?

Comment: @Rich yes, I need a method or something that have an Object as a parameter and returns a group of <Object, String> with the instance and the field name.

Comment: For what reason do you need this? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988148/all-references-to-an-object

Comment: @Colin I need this to create a variable state change, which have to record every instances that have a reference to the dirty variable (this is not going to run in production).

Comment: @Colin, thanks for the link (don't understand how that didn't appeared in my google search). I had a solution in mind, and it's probably the one I'm goign to use (just asked it hoping that there's an easy solution): AOP. I'm going to take a look at JVMTI to see what can de done (and the effort)

Comment: @ColinD I don't think that JVMTI it's the way to go here, I've never played with it before and this is one of those features to deliver "yesterday". I'm going to think about doing it with AOP (aspectj rules!) and I'll post here later how I did it (if the question doesn't get closed until then).

Answer (score 2):

"Pure" Java solution: not sure if it works for you, but if you can afford to wrap your object and access it only via wrapper, then you can try `WeakHashMap`:

```
public class Wrapper {
    private final Object yourObject;

    private final WeakHashMap<Object, Object> accessors = new WeakHashMap<Object, Object>();

    public Wrapper(Object yourObject) {
        this.yourObject = yourObject;
    }

// add synchronized if you want thread-safety.
    public Object getYourObject(Object accessor) {
        accessors.put(accessor, accessor);
        return yourObject;
    }

// add synchronized if you want thread-safety.
    public Object[] getAccessors() {
        return accessors.keySet().toArray(new Object[accessors.keySet().size()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: great advice, I think I'll use it with AOP to fill that acessor.